# How to achieve rounded edges on ghost model

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, bezier-curves

I found this "Ghost" image online, and I tried recreating it in Blender.

[image]

I started with a Cube then applied a Subdivision to get the head, but my problem was creating the tail.

[image]

How to get that perfect rounded tail?

I even tried it with Cylinder instead of Cube, still failed. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, you should sculpt it, but if you want to model it here is an example:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you think it should be sculpted? Your way looks just fine to me.. simple, stylized, basically regular and geometric before deformation...

Comment: You have more freedom and control with the form when you sculpt and is faster in my opinion, anyway, this is just my preference it works just fine either way.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks. I didn't think about starting it from a Circle. Total beginner.
I didn't figure out how to separate those vertices. I just select each one and pressed "V" to separate them one by one. I'm sure there's an easier way.

[image]

Anyway here's my final result. **Thanks again :)**
[image]

[image]

[image]